# Append column to dataframe containing count of duplicates on another row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

New to Python, using 3.x

I have a large CSV containing a list of customer names and addresses. 
[Name, City, State]

I am wanting to create a 4th column that is a count of the total number of customers living in the current customer's state.

So for example:

```
Joe, Dallas, TX
Steve, Austin, TX
Alex, Denver, CO
```

would become:

```
Joe, Dallas, TX, 2 
Steve, Austin, TX, 2
Alex, Denver, CO, 1
```

I am able to read the file in, and then use groupby to create a Series that contains the values for the 4th column, but I can't figure out how to take that series and match it against the million+ rows in my actual file.

```
import pandas as pd
mydata=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\customerlist.csv', index_col=False)
mydata=mydata.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep='first')
mydata['state']=mydata['state'].str.strip()
stateinstalls=(mydata.groupby(mydata.state, as_index=False).size())
```

stateinstalls gives me a series [2,1] but I lose the corresponding state([TX, CO]). It needs to be a tuple, so that I can then go back and iterate through all rows of my spreadsheet and say something like:

```
if mydata['state'].isin(stateinstalls(0))
mydata[row]=stateinstalls(1)
```

I feel very lost. I know there has to be a far simpler way to do this. Like even in place within the array (like a countif type function).

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: You can do `df['Count']=df.groupby('State').State.transform('count')
`

Comment: Wow... I have no idea how that works, but it worked perfectly. I will read up on these commands and see if I can understand better. Thank you, thank you, thank you!